# How to Add an Existing Item to a Project Programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I programmatically add an item to a project?

Something similar to

```
public void AddExistingItem(string projectPath, string existingItemPath)
{
    //I'm making up the Project class here as an example
    Project p = new Project(projectPath);
    p.AddExistingItem(existingItemPath);
}
```

I want to mimic Visual Studio's Add Existing Item functionality.

[image: Add Existing Item]

Comment: what issues are you having for example when you run the code that you have posted

Comment: I made the project class up. I'm not sure what class I should use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add an existing form to a new project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316650/how-do-you-add-an-existing-form-to-a-new-project)

Comment: I added my comment prior to you adding your code change Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to EnvDTE.dll, and then use [`ProjectItems.AddFromFile` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfromfile.aspx)
As you can read on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.aspx), you must set the **Embed Interop Types** property of the assembly to `false` if you add a reference to EnvDTE.dll

Comment: The link provided provide instructions to create a new project. How can you add a new Item in an existing project? Could you provide any helpful link?

Comment: @user8657231 I'm sorry, I wrote this answer more than 7 years ago and have no clue about this situation anymore. Your search is as good as mine.

Answer (score 3):

VisualStudio project is just a XML file so you can open it using XDocument or XmlDocument and edit.

Comment: source control won't know that you added a new file.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman Not sure that I understand why it won't know? It will be update of xml file that source control will recognize.

Comment: scc will see that the `csproj` has changed, but won't detect the added file. Obviously, that functionality is handled by the `Add New/Existing Item` feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public void createProjectItem(DTE2 dte)
{
    //Adds a new Class to an existing Visual Basic project.
    Solution2 soln;
    Project prj;
    soln = (Solution2)_applicationObject.Solution;
    ProjectItem prjItem;
    String itemPath;
    // Point to the first project (the Visual Basic project).
    prj = soln.Projects.Item(1);
    // Retrieve the path to the class template.
    itemPath = soln.GetProjectItemTemplate("Class.zip", "vbproj");
    //Create a new project item based on the template, in this
    // case, a Class.
    prjItem = prj.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(itemPath, "MyNewClass");
}
```

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228774.aspx