# VS2017 C# Importing WinForms generates namespace errors

Tags: c#, winforms, import, visual-studio-2017, namespaces

I have two solutions, one functional, the other experimental.  I made some forms and code that I want to import from Experimental to Functional.

I followed directions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316650/how-do-you-add-an-existing-form-to-a-new-project) to import the forms.

1. Add the existing files (cs, designer, and resx) from the Experimental folder
2. Exclude them from solution
3. Add them again from the Functional folder
4. Done (sort of)

What I encountered was that I needed to change the namespace on the FormOne.Designer.cs file to match that of the Functional solution:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
```

Changed to:

```
namespace ProjName
```

After doing that and saving it worked for FormOne.

But following the exact same procedure (one form at a time) for FormTwo and FormThree fails.  When I try to build or rebuild the solution or project I get:

```
FormTwo.Dispose(bool): no suitable method found to override
```

I get this same error for both FormTwo and FormThree.  I did a copy/paste of the namespace line to ensure I did not make a typo when entering it.

Comment: Post the minimum amount of code necessary to replicate the error

Comment: When you were adjustng the namespaces (not needed; you can just import missing ones) did you accidentally remove the declaration that FormTwo inherits from Form?

Answer (score 0):

Forms use the `partial` class functionality to combine the `Form1` in the code file you edit (`Form1.cs`) with the `Form1` in the file the designer edits (`Form1.Designer.cs`)

The designer code overrides `Dispose()`, a method that it can override because the `Form1` class in Form1.cs inherits from `Form`, which has an overridable `Dispose()`. The `partial class Form1` in the designer file doesn't inherit anything (it can't inherit `Form` also because that is already done in `Form1.cs`; you can't inherit twice)

If you change the namespace of the `Form1` class in the Form1.cs class and forget to change the namespace of the class in the Form1.Designer.cs you will cause two classes both called `Form1` in your project, in different namespaces. The `Form1 in the Designer file, that doesn't inherit from Form, cannot thus have a`Dispose()` to override:

[image]

FWIW you don't NEED to edit the namespaces; your forms from the old namespace can be used in the forms of the new namespace just by adding a "using OldNamespace" at the top of the forms in the new namespace

Comment: So I figured out that JUST typing in or copy/pasting the new namespace was not enough.  Afterwards, I had to actually select the Rename function from the right click menu and run that.  Then open the tab up for the form GUI and let it digest the new changes for a few seconds.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter how the namespace comes to be changed (direct edit, find replace, rename function etc) it just has to be consistent between FormX.cs and FormX.Designer.cs, for the reasons i give above.